# Deluge torrent client continue downloading files in a new Ubuntu installation, from the same state that was in a broken Ubuntu installation

Tags: deluge, torrent-client

My Ubuntu has broken. I had downloaded some files and I was downloading other files using Deluge Torrent client. I would like to install Deluge in the new Ubuntu installation that I am going to do, and be able to continue dowwnloading those files that I was downloading but that did not finished downloading, from the same state that they were (example 20% of file A had already been downloaded).

I have seen that exists a directory with the .torrent files and 2 files named `torrents.fastresume` and `torrents.state`

```
/william/.config/deluge/state
```

If I copy those files in the `state` directory in the new Ubuntu installation after installing Deluge, will I be able to continue Deluge in the same state that was in the broken Ubuntu installation?

All the files downloaded using Deluge (those ones that have fully downloaded and those ones that have partially downloaded) are stored in an external hard drive

Comment: You need to copy over the partially downloaded files so Deluge can put them together when it has finished downloading.

Comment: I have all the partially downloaded files in an external hard drive (I should have mentiones that)

Comment: Did you have Deluge(old) set to use the external, or did you copy the files over manually?

Comment: @crip659 Deluge was configured to store the files in the external hard drive

Comment: It might be possible to configure the new Deluge the same and just reopen the torrent file of the partial download.

Comment: @crip659 If I copy the content of the old core.conf in the new core.conf and I also copy the .torrent files stored in the old /home/william/.config/deluge/state in the new /home/william/.config/deluge/state, will I be able to continue downloading the partially downloaded torrents?

Comment: I would think so, as long as both old ubuntu and deluge are the same versions as the new ones.